# Merging instances of objects in a list by attribute

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have an object Person which has firstName, lastName and email

```java
class Person {
   String firstname;
   String lastName;
   String email;
}
```

I have a list of `Person` where there are potentially multiple `Persons` of the same `firstName` and `lastName` and I want to merge these by their email address with a delimiter.

i.e.
Person A =

```json
{
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Guiney",
    "email": "david.guiney@gmail.com"
}
```

Person B =

```json
{
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Guiney",
    "email": "guiney.david@hotmail.com"
}
```

And I want these to be merged into

```json
{
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Guiney",
    "email": "david.guiney@gmail.com;guiney.david@hotmail.com"
}
```

So as to create a unique instance in my list.

Comment: `stream()` and `filter()` are your friends - give it a whirl and let us know how we can help.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."
even if it is no homework.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because No attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends what you define as unique or equal. This could then be expressed by the equals and hashCode Method.
2. you can use the java.util.stream.Collectors#toMap Method to provide a merge function and map your list to a map. In the merge function you can implement the logic how 2 objects with the same "key" should be handled.

   public class Person
   {
   public Person(String firstname, String lastName, String email)
   {
   this.firstname = firstname;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   this.email = email;
   }

   ```
    String firstname;
    String lastName;
    String email;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return Objects.equals(firstname, person.firstname) && Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Objects.hash(firstname, lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Person{" +
            "firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(new Person("David", "Guiney", "david.guiney@gmail.com"),
            new Person("David", "Guiney", "david.guiney@gmail.com"),
            new Person("Andreas", "Radauer", "please_no@spam.com")
        );

        Map<Integer, Person> uniquePersons =
            persons.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Person::hashCode,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (person1, person2) -> {
                        person1.email = person1.email + ";" + person2.email; // this could be improved
                        return person1;
                    }
                ));

        System.out.println(uniquePersons.values());
    }
   ```

   }

If you don't want to use equals and hashCode for this usecase you can of course just provide an own getKey Logic

Comment: Thank you Andreas, this was exactly what I needed. Superb.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the objects in the list one by one but the problem is the time complexity. it will be in form O(n^2).

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
            if(list.get(i).firstName.equals(list.get(j).firstName) && list.get(i).lastName.equals(list.get(j).lastName)){
                list.get(i).email += ";"+list.get(j).email;
                list.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if persons can have several emails, I would reflect that in the Person class by having an "emails" attribute storing collection of emails.

Then you can use Java 8 Streams.

```
public class Person {

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private List<String> emails;// if a person is susceptible to have several emails, use a collection and not a single String

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.emails = new ArrayList<>();
    this.emails.add(email);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("David", "Guiney", "david.guiney@gmail.com"),
            new Person("Jean", "Patrick", "jp@pluton.com"),
            new Person("David", "Guiney", "david.guiney@hotmail.com"),
            new Person("Bruce", "Lee", "bl@kungfu.com")
    );

    // Group together the Person instances having the same firstname and same lastname
    Map<List<String>, Person> keyToPerson = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            p -> Arrays.asList(p.firstName, p.lastName),// define the key allowing to group person as the combination of firstname and lastname
            Function.identity(),// what is associated to the key. Here we want the Person instance itself
            (p1, p2) -> {// the logic to solve collision, i.e. instances having the same key
                p1.emails.addAll(p2.emails);// add the email(s) of the second instances in the email of the first instance
                return p1;
            }
    ));
    keyToPerson.values().forEach(p -> {
        System.out.println(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName + " (" + String.join("; ", p.emails) + ")");
    });
}
```

}

It should print somethink like that

```
David Guiney (david.guiney@gmail.com; david.guiney@hotmail.com)
Bruce Lee (bl@kungfu.com)
Jean Patrick (jp@pluton.com)
```

You could also redefine equals and hashcode method of the Person class to implement how to group 2 instances together.

Comment: Thank you, using a List of emails in the Person object would be an ideal solution, but unfortunately making that change would break a lot of other code. (The actual object I'm working with is a more complex model). The 1st response above gives the ideal solution what works for me.